# No reconoce la app 'home' pero está dentro de installed_apps

Tags: python, django

Al ejecutar runserver parece que no reconoce las app que están en installed_apps.

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

settings > base.py

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    #'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
    'applications.home',
    'applications.users',
    'applications.installation',
    'applications.element',
    'applications.device',
    'applications.consumable',
    'applications.incidence',
    'applications.repair',
    'applications.map',
    'applications.preventive',
    'applications.company',
    'applications.employee',
    #'applications.administrativeRequirement',
    #'applications.streetMap',
    'applications.cleaning',
    'home'
)

BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}

"""THIRD_PARTY_APPS = ()"""

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

Árbol de archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que tienes tu `apps.py` pero en el settings no registras el config de tu app que presubiblemente se llamaría `HomeConfig`

Answer (score 0):

Si tu árbol de archivos es correcto ya estas registrando la app con:

```
LOCAL_APPS = (
    'applications.home',
)
```

Ya que tu app se encuentra en el directorio /applications/home/

Si quieres cargar tu aplicación solo como 'home' mueve el directorio de esa app un nivel arriba, en el nivel donde esta tu manage.py

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que dentro de la aplicación 'applications >home > apps.py' estaba la aplicación declarada como 'home' y no como 'applications.home'. Entonces no lo reconocía.

Aparecía así (y devolvía error):

```
class HomeConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'home'
```

Y debe aparecer así:

```
class HomeConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'applications.home'
```

Lo que no comprendo bien es por qué ahora me ha devuelto este error, y nunca antes me devolvía cuando desde el inicio 'home' estuvo dentro del directorio 'applications'. Almenos queda solucionado.